# clustering and matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-mining, fuzzy

I'm trying to cluster some data I have from the KDD 1999 cup dataset

the output from the file looks like this:

```
0,tcp,http,SF,239,486,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,8,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00,19,19,1.00,0.00,0.05,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,normal.
```

with 48 thousand different records in that format. I have cleaned the data up and removed the text keeping only the numbers. The output looks like this now:

[image]

I created a comma delimited file in excel and saved as a csv file then created a data source from the csv file in matlab, ive tryed running it through the fcm toolbox in matlab (findcluster outputs 38 data types which is expected with 38 columns).

The clusters however don't look like clusters or its not accepting and working the way I need it to.

Could anyone help finding the clusters? Im new to matlab so don't have any experience and I'm also new to clustering.

The method:

1. Chose number of clusters (K)
2. Initialize centroids (K patterns randomly chosen from data set)
3. Assign each pattern to the cluster with closest centroid
4. Calculate means of each cluster to be its new centroid
5. Repeat step 3 until a stopping criteria is met (no pattern move to another cluster)

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

```
load kddcup1.dat
plot(kddcup1(:,1),kddcup1(:,2),'o')  
[center,U,objFcn] = fcm(kddcup1,2);
Iteration count = 1, obj. fcn = 253224062681230720.000000
Iteration count = 2, obj. fcn = 241493132059137410.000000
Iteration count = 3, obj. fcn = 241484544542298110.000000
Iteration count = 4, obj. fcn = 241439204971005280.000000
Iteration count = 5, obj. fcn = 241090628742523840.000000
Iteration count = 6, obj. fcn = 239363408546874750.000000
Iteration count = 7, obj. fcn = 238580863900727680.000000
Iteration count = 8, obj. fcn = 238346826370420990.000000
Iteration count = 9, obj. fcn = 237617756429912510.000000
Iteration count = 10, obj. fcn = 226364785036628320.000000
Iteration count = 11, obj. fcn = 94590774984961184.000000
Iteration count = 12, obj. fcn = 2220521449216102.500000
Iteration count = 13, obj. fcn = 2220521273191876.200000
Iteration count = 14, obj. fcn = 2220521273191876.700000
Iteration count = 15, obj. fcn = 2220521273191876.700000

figure
plot(objFcn)
title('Objective Function Values')
xlabel('Iteration Count')
ylabel('Objective Function Value')

    maxU = max(U);
    index1 = find(U(1, :) == maxU);
    index2 = find(U(2, :) == maxU);
    figure
    line(kddcup1(index1, 1), kddcup1(index1, 2), 'linestyle',...
    'none','marker', 'o','color','g');
    line(kddcup1(index2,1),kddcup1(index2,2),'linestyle',...
    'none','marker', 'x','color','r');
    hold on
    plot(center(1,1),center(1,2),'ko','markersize',15,'LineWidth',2)
    plot(center(2,1),center(2,2),'kx','markersize',15,'LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: really dont know what im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include the part of your code where you generate the clusters?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "C#"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are new to machine-learning/data-mining, you shouldn't tackle such advanced problems. After all, the data you are working with was used in a competition (KDD Cup'99), so don't expect it to be easy!

Besides the data was intended for a classification task (supervised learning), where the goal is predict the correct class (bad/good connection). You seem to be interested in clustering (unsupervised learning), which is generally more difficult.

This sort of dataset requires a lot of preprocessing and clever feature extraction. People usually employ domain knowledge (network intrusion detection) to obtain better features from the raw data.. Directly applying simple algorithms like K-means will generally yield poor results.

For starters, you need to normalize the attributes to be of the same scale: when computing the euclidean distance as part of step 3 in your method, the features with values such as `239` and `486` will dominate over the other features with small values as `0.05`, thus disrupting the result.

Another point to remember is that too many attributes can be a bad thing (curse of dimensionality). Thus you should look into feature selection or dimensionality reduction techniques.

Finally, I suggest you familiarize yourself with a simpler dataset...