# clustering data outputs irregular plot graph 

Tags: matlab, sorting, random, cluster-analysis, normalization

Ok I will run down what im trying to achieve and how I tryed to achieve it then I will explain why I tryed this method.

I have data from the KDD cup 1999 in its original format the data has 494k of rows with 42 columns.

My goal is trying to cluster this data unsupervised. From a previous question here:

[clustering and matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715891/clustering-and-matlab)

I recieved this feedback:

> For starters, you need to normalize the attributes to be of the same
>   scale: when computing the euclidean distance as part of step 3 in your
>   method, the features with values such as 239 and 486 will dominate
>   over the other features with small values as 0.05, thus disrupting the
>   result.
>
> Another point to remember is that too many attributes can be a bad
>   thing (curse of dimensionality). Thus you should look into feature
>   selection or dimensionality reduction techniques.

So the first thing I went about doing was addressing the feature selection which is related to this article: http://narensportal.com/papers/datamining-classification-algorithm.aspx#_sec-2-1

and looks like this after selecting the necessary features:

[image]

So for the clustering I removed the discrete values which left me with 3 columns with numeric data, I then went about removing the duplicate rows see: [junk, index and unique on a matrix (how to keep matrix format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781749/junk-index-and-unique-on-a-matrix-how-to-keep-matrix-format) in the file which reduced the 3 columns from 494k to 67k which was done like so:

```
[M,ind] = unique(data, 'rows', 'first');
[~,ind] = sort(ind);
M = M(ind,:);
```

I then used the random permutation to reduce the file size from 67k to 1000 like so:

```
m = 1000;
n = 3;

%# pick random rows
indX = randperm( size(M,1) );
indX = indX(1:m);

%# pick random columns
indY = randperm( size(M,2) );
indY = indY(1:n);

%# filter data
data = M(indX,indY)
```

So now I have a file with 3 of my features which I selected I have removed duplicate records and used the random permutation to further reduce the dataset my last goal was to normalize this data and I did this with:

```
normalized_data = data/norm(data);
```

I then used the following K-means script:

```
%% generate clusters
K = 4;

%% cluster
opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);

%% plot data+clusters
figure, hold on
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 200, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
%% plot clusters quality
figure
[silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
avrgScore = mean(silh);

%% Assign data to clusters
% calculate distance (squared) of all instances to each cluster centroid
D = zeros(numObservarations, K);     % init distances
for k=1:K
%d = sum((x-y).^2).^0.5
D(:,k) = sum( ((data - repmat(clusters(k,:),numObservarations,1)).^2), 2);
end

% find  for all instances the cluster closet to it
[minDists, clusterIndices] = min(D, [], 2);
% compare it with what you expect it to be
sum(clusterIndices == clustIDX)
```

But my results are still coming out like my original question I asked here: [clustering and matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715891/clustering-and-matlab)

Here is what the data looks like when plotted:

[image]

and:

[image]

Can anyone help solve this problem, are the methods im using not the correct methods or is there something im missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like to say thanks to cyborg and Amro for helping, I realized that rather than create my own pre-processing I kept the dimensions as such and I finally managed to get some clustered data!

Out put!

[image]

Ofcourse I still have some outliers but if I could get rid of them and plot the graph from -0.2 - 0.2 im sure it would look alot better. But if you look at the original attempt I seem to be getting there!

```
  %% load data
    %# read the list of features
    fid = fopen('kddcup.names','rt');
    C = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'Delimiter',':', 'HeaderLines',1);
    fclose(fid);

    %# determine type of features
    C{2} = regexprep(C{2}, '.$','');              %# remove "." at the end
    attribNom = [ismember(C{2},'symbolic');true]; %# nominal features

    %# build format string used to read/parse the actual data
    frmt = cell(1,numel(C{1}));
    frmt( ismember(C{2},'continuous') ) = {'%f'}; %# numeric features: read as number
    frmt( ismember(C{2},'symbolic') ) = {'%s'};   %# nominal features: read as string
    frmt = [frmt{:}];
    frmt = [frmt '%s'];                           %# add the class attribute

    %# read dataset
    fid = fopen('kddcup.data_10_percent_corrected','rt');
    C = textscan(fid, frmt, 'Delimiter',',');
    fclose(fid);

    %# convert nominal attributes to numeric
    ind = find(attribNom);
    G = cell(numel(ind),1);
    for i=1:numel(ind)
        [C{ind(i)},G{i}] = grp2idx( C{ind(i)} );
    end

    %# all numeric dataset
    fulldata = cell2mat(C);
    %% dimensionality reduction 
    columns = 42
    [U,S,V]=svds(fulldata,columns)
    %% randomly select dataset
    rows = 5000;
    %# pick random rows
    indX = randperm( size(fulldata,1) );
    indX = indX(1:rows);
    %# pick random columns
    indY = randperm( size(fulldata,2) );
    indY = indY(1:columns);
    %# filter data
    data = U(indX,indY)
    %% apply normalization method to every cell
    data = data./repmat(sqrt(sum(data.^2)),size(data,1),1)
    %% generate sample data
    K = 4;
    numObservarations = 5000;
    dimensions = 42;
    %% cluster
    opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
    [clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
    'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);
    %% plot data+clusters
    figure, hold on
    scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 5, clustIDX, 'filled')
    scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 100, (1:K)', 'filled')
    hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
    %% plot clusters quality
    figure
    [silh,h] = silhouette(data, clustIDX);
    avrgScore = mean(silh);
    %% Assign data to clusters
    % calculate distance (squared) of all instances to each cluster centroid
    D = zeros(numObservarations, K);     % init distances
    for k=1:K
    %d = sum((x-y).^2).^0.5
    D(:,k) = sum( ((data - repmat(clusters(k,:),numObservarations,1)).^2), 2);
    end
    % find  for all instances the cluster closet to it
    [minDists, clusterIndices] = min(D, [], 2);
    % compare it with what you expect it to be
    sum(clusterIndices == clustIDX)
```

Comment: ...or, instead of getting rid of the outliers you could examine them in more detail. When you are working on anomaly detection, often the outliers are more interesting than the "well-behaved" points. Something interesting might be happening there.

Comment: ahh good point Bob infact the outlies may be the r2l and u2r attacks, I will investigate this further! +1 for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the normalization: `data/norm(data);`. What you probably need to do is
to use: `data_normed = data./repmat(sqrt(sum(data.^2)),size(data,1),1)`. This computes the norm of every column of `data`, then it duplicates the answer to the original size of `data`, then it divides `data` by the norms of the columns.

Comment:

A better way to reduce the dimensionality of the number of features is `[U,S,V]=svd(data); U=U(:,1:m)` or for sparse data `[U,S,V]=svds(data,m)`. It might loose some information in the way, but it's much better than random picking.

Comment: `[U,S,V]=svds(data,m)` doesnt reduce the size of the matrix?

Comment: Um... did you read *all* the feedback from your earlier post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715891/clustering-and-matlab ? It's suggested there you cut your teeth first on something easier as the data you are working with are from a *very hard problem*. Nevertheless, if you want to reduce the dimensionality of the data (and you probably do, since such high-dimensional data has properties that impact on these kinds of approaches) then a good survey of preprocessing schemes you could initially try can be found at http://www.llnl.gov/casc/sapphire/pubs/148494.pdf.